# How to use adjective followed by two separate things that are being described?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I am trying to formulate the following sentence:
Rob has to find suitable shirt and hat.

Is this grammatically correct? it feels a bit strange to me because there is no "a" or "the" for either shirt or hat. I want the sentence to mean: Rob has to find a suitable shirt and a suitable hat. but this seems too redundant. Any clarification is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need at least one article:

> Rob has to find **a** suitable shirt and hat.

You don't have to provide an article for "hat," or repeat the adjective *suitable*; the ones attached to "shirt" can "extend" to hat.

And of course you wouldn't need an article with a plural:

> Rob has to find suitable socks.

That means, if you add a singular to a plural, you do have to give it an article:

> Rob has to find suitable socks and a hat.

... But this can get a little unclear: does "suitable" still apply to "hat"? We're not sure. Maybe in this case it's better to reorganize the sentence.